# Error in Next.js TypeScript project: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a Next.js TypeScript project, and I've encountered a runtime error that I'm having trouble understanding. The error message is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

This error occurs in my code when I attempt to call the toLowerCase() method on a variable named email. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
email = email.toLowerCase();
```

I have reactStrictMode set to true in my next.config.js file, and I'm wondering why this error doesn't get caught during the build process when I run yarn build.

Is there a way to ensure that potential runtime errors like this one are caught during the build process in a Next.js TypeScript project? Or is there something specific I need to do to handle this error correctly in my code?

If I use

```
email = email?.toLowerCase();
```

then no error will be raise. But why `yarn build` not notice me?

Comment: You have somehow convinced TypeScript that this `email` variable cannot be undefined, yet at runtime it turns out to be undefined. You'd have to provide more context as to how this variable is declared and how it is assigned to give more specific information.

Comment: It would be better if you add a code sample to get clarity.

Comment: We would need more information, including the source of the email binding and it's type.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying since `email` is `undefined` it can't find the `toLowerCase` function property (since `undefined has no properties).

> I'm wondering why this error doesn't get caught during the build process when I run yarn build.

The code doesn't know til runtime what the value of email is going to be, so the Typescript compiler can not warn against a TypeError like this.

To protect against this, you should explicitly assign what type `email` can be, so that the Typescript compiler can warn you if you do something incorrect.

For example, in your followup example `email = email?.toLowerCase();`, you're saying "email can be a string or undefined and I'll handle both" (that `?.` operator gracefully handles `falsey` values).

If you don't want to allow `undefined` values for `email`, then when you first define `email`, you could also mandate it to be a `string`. I haven't seen the rest of your code, but I'm assuming its something along the lines of:

```
let email;
const user = await fetchUser();
if (user) {
    email = user.email;
}
```

It's impossible for me to know exactly what the flow is but the important part here is that `email` is not explicitly typed as a `string` and wherever you get `email` from is not typed correctly either.

You could change that first line to be `let email: string = "";` and then if `user.email` wasn't also set as a string, the compiler would complain.

See this Typescript Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBArgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqEC2AhgJYA2AXFHMIsQHYDmUAPrHQCYQBm9E7A3JgC+gzKQjA8RMpWq1GqKACIlogMYB7OtVgJEARkrwkirLikkKypQBphogpcXGDAOkdl+QA

You would then know you need to change your user type so the email is definitely defined as a string, or add the handling code you suggest in your answer to allow for falsey values.

If you update your question with more context (or better yet, a reproducible example on something like CodeSandbox or Typescript Playground!) then the community will be able to give you more specific help.